# Не присваивается программно BackgroundImage кнопке, c#

Tags: c#, winforms, файлы, button

Пытаюсь при определенном действии присвоить кнопке картинку, в отладчике пишет что все работает, но на кнопке она не отображается:

```
  StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(@"buttons\" + nameFile + ".txt"); //Открываем файл для чтения
  string str = ""; //Объявляем переменную, в которую будем записывать текст из файла
  int count = 1;
  while (!streamReader.EndOfStream) //Цикл длиться пока не будет достигнут конец файла
  {
        str += streamReader.ReadLine(); //В переменную str по строчно записываем содержимое файла
        if (count == 4) pb.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(str);
        count++;
        str = "";
  }
  if (pb.BackgroundImage == null)
  {
        pb.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(@"img\X.png");
  }
  streamReader.Close();
```

Картинка должна присваиваться в блоке "if", адрес правильный.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Значит `pb.BackgroundImage` не равно null или `Image.FromFile(@"img\X.png")` равно null

Посмотрите в отладчике значения переменных

Comment: В отладчике в if заходит, и в результате pb.BackgroundImage получает Bitmap

Comment: Что именно проверить, я вроде все просмотрел?

Comment: Тут вариантов несколько: pb - это что? Как вы получили переменную? Она ссылается на контрол на форме? Если ли другие потоки меняющие это свойство? Как настроен контрол? На нем отображаются картинки или он настроен на отображение только текста?

Comment: pb - это кнопка, получаю ее через foreach 
(Control pb in Controls) 
            {
                if (pb is Button)